# What is the meaning of an algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition

An algebra $A(*,\hat{} ,\sim)$ is said to be Boolean algebra if it satisfies some conditions...In this statement what is the meaning of starting word an algebra?

Comment: @glacier : Do you think Soft question tag is necessary?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I thought this was an open-ended question. If you feel that the tag should be removed, however, then I understand.

Comment: open ended? I do not know what you are thinking but he is asking for a definition of algebra i guess....

Comment: @glacier Since the question seems to be asking what the definition of a [Boolean algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_%28structure%29), or an algebra (viewed as an algebraic object in general), I don't believe the soft-question tag is appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

An algebra consists of a set with some operation(s) (and possibly relations).

A Boolean algebra consists of a set with two binary operations "K" and "A", and a unary opeartion "N", two special elements "0" and "1" such that for all p, q, r:

KKpqr=KpKqr, AApqr=ApAqr (associative laws)

Kpq=Kqp, Apq=Aqp (commutative laws)

KpApq=p, ApKpq=p (absorption laws)

KpAqr=AKpqKpr, ApKqr=KApqApr (distributive laws)

KpNp=0, ApNp=1 (complement laws)